# How to pass directive name to template - Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that creates a bunch of similar widgets.  Each widget houses and different directive.  Here is the template that I use to create my widget:

```
template: '<li><div {{widgetModel.directiveName}}></div></li>'
```

I am wanting the variables to be reconciled and or the template to declare the directive that needs to be used.  The template will then be:

```
template: '<li><div directive-name></div></li>'
```

I then want it to act as a normal directive with an attribute name of `directiveName`.  This is not happening with the current code and I do not know how to make it behave like I need.  The directiveName directive can really be anything.

Comment: one line of code doesn't explain problem. What gets output from template now? What are you expecting for output? directives can be identified in markup 3 different ways

Comment: Are you using directive's name dash-delimited instead of camelCase?

Comment: no, I updated my question.

Comment: This can give you some idea http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/8dbCP/

Answer (score 1):

You could do those changes at compile function:

```
angular.module('myWidgets', [])
  .directive('multiDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function(element, attrs)
        {
            var htmlText = '<ul>' +
                    '<li ' + attrs.directiveName + '>' + '</li>' +
                '</ul>';
            element.replaceWith(htmlText);
        }
    }
})
```

And then you could call it like this:

```
<multi-directive directive-name='widget1' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I made [a CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qwCpv) based on the hints in the [Angular Dynamic Templates](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/) blog post that I saw referenced in another post.

In order to have HTML that looks like the following:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="dir in dirs">
    <div smart />
  </div>
</div>
```

and assuming that your controller looks something like this:

```
function ExampleCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.dirs = ["<div dir-a />","<div dir-b />"];
}
```

The `smart` directive could look like this:

```
.directive('smart', function($compile) {
   return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      link: function (scope, element) {
         element.html(scope.dir);
         $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      }
   };
});
```